# In Meteor JS, what is "doc" in the ownsDocument variable?

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is from the Discover Meteor book:

lib/permissions.js

```
// check that the userId specified owns the documents
ownsDocument = function(userId, doc) {
  return doc && doc.userId === userId;
}
```

collections/posts.js

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

Posts.allow({
  update: ownsDocument,
  remove: ownsDocument
});

Meteor.methods({
...
```

So ownsDocument is a global variable that contains a function which takes two parameters, the userID and doc.

Later, in posts.js when you are creating the Posts.allow hash, the keys "update" and "remove" are assigned to ownsDocument, but no parameters are being passed in.

Uhhhh... and it somehow works. How does it know what userID and doc are if it's not being passed in? And what is 'doc' referring to anyway?

Comment: doc - it's any document in Post collection. When you create new post, you add author ID, current logged in user, to userId. This permissions mean what add new post can any registered user, but update and delete you can only own posts

Answer (score 2):

This is first class functions. You could see it as though the `ownsDocument`s in the `Posts.allow` are replaced by the entire `ownsDocument` function:

```
ownsDocument = function(userId, doc) {
  return doc && doc.userId === userId;
}

Posts.allow({
  update: ownsDocument,
  remove: ownsDocument
});

// Can be seen as equivalent to:

Posts.allow({
  update: function(userId, doc) {
    return doc && doc.userId === userId;
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc) {
    return doc && doc.userId === userId;
  }
});
```

The advantage is that you avoid repeating yourself, and if you want to update `ownsDocument` later, you only have to change it in one place. It could also have been written like this:

```
Posts.allow({
  update: function(userId, doc) {
    return ownsDocument(userId, doc);
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc) {
    return ownsDocument(userId, doc);
  }
});
```